# How can i find close curved line on an image in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, geometry

community,

Is there any way you can find an close curved line on an image using numpy and opencv or anything else (sample images attached)

close curved line image:
[image]
or simply:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYlht.jpg)

unclose curved line image:
[image]
or simply:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnuUq.jpg)

I need this function to search entire image and if there is one return me true else return false, thanks and happy coding

```
def check_close_curved_line_on_img(img):
    // logic here 
        if has_close_curved_line:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Can you provide an example image with and without close curved lines?

Comment: For me, it is not clear what you want. Do you want to segment (separate) the text from the background?

Comment: @Pantelis, check my last edit pls,

Comment: @stateMachine no i don't want that ( i want to know if any close curved line exist in my image )

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a combination of `floodFill` and `erode` from opencv. The code below worked on the examples provided.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('unclosed.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# floodFill
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
mask = np.zeros((np.array(img.shape)+2), np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(img, mask, (0,0), (255))

# erode
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
img = cv2.erode(img, np.ones((3,3)))

# show image
cv2.imshow('show', img)
if img.sum() > 0:
    print('Closed curve detected')
else:
    print('Closed curve was not detected')
```

Comment: not sure if you tested your code but your code always gives me this output no matter what "Closed curve detected"